# array_push is couting the value instead of adding

Tags: php, array-push

When I insert the value to the array its counting the value instaed of adding.

I have the below array named $staff_group_arr

```
Array ( [0] => All Rights User [1] => Operation [2] => Supritendent [3] => Admin Department [4] => Accounts [5] => Transportation )
```

I am donig like this

```
$glo_staff_array = array_push($staff_group_arr, "Global", "Managers");

print_r($glo_staff_array );
```

Result is coming as 8

Please let me know where is the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/array_push#refsect1-function.array-push-returnvalues):

> **Description**
>
> int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

The ampersand, `&`, is the reference operator. This means that the function will modify the parameter, as opposed to returning a modified version of the parameter:

```
array_push($staff_group_arr, "Global", "Managers");
print_r($staff_group_arr);
```

You can also append stuff the simple way:

```
$staff_group_arr[] = 'Global';
$staff_group_arr[] = 'Managers';
print_r($staff_group_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_push](http://www.php.net/array_push) returns new number of elements in the array.
If you wan to see your new array do:

```
print_r($staff_group_arr);
```